# Is it possible to print a result generated in PHP in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I am doing a program that does some calculations and in the end generates the result assign to the variable `$result`, the data is entered using a web form `<form method = "POST" action = "file.php">`

For example in `<form>` / web form the user can enter numbers using text fields and it submits to file.php  and file.php calculates value and assign to `$result` variable.

Eg. 
`$result = $value1 + $value2`

And what I want is that in the HTML page (even if you have to reload the page) show something like:

"Your value equals 5"

Where 5 is what I left in `$result`.

What I want to know is that what is the convenient / right way of displaying the results in HTML page in PHP.

Comment: show your html form and php code @CarlosDayan

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "yes or no?" Assume that it *is* possible, try something ,and ask about that if you get stuck. Please see [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

On your file.php

```
<?php 
     $value_1 = intval($_POST['value1']);
     $value_2 = intval($_POST['value2']);

     $result = $value_1 + $value_2;

     echo "Your value equals ".$result;

 ?>
```

You can echo it to your file.php

But if you want to redirect it to other html page with php you can create a session variable to save your `$result` just like this:

```
$_SESSION['result'] = $result; //the sum of the val_1 and val_2
```

Then just echo this to your other html page.

```
echo $_SESSION['result'];
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Vote, not for your answer, that's because you answered. Keep sharing. :-)